# Accessing Array Element in php codeigniter does not work

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Accessing array element  "id" in codeigniter does not work. Cant find a possible cause to fail. If anyone can show the proper way to do that will be helpful,

**My View**

```
<form name ="userinput" onsubmit="return test()" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/patient/saveNewExaminationChart/<?php echo $pd['id']; ?>" method="post">
```

**`<?php echo $pd['id']; ?>` 
For this part i want to get the id number passed by controller to view.**

**My Controller**

```
public function editPeriodicalDetails(){

        $pid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('patient_model');
        $patient['pd'] = $this->patient_model->getPeriodicalChart($pid);


        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Header');
        $this->load->view('Patient/editPeriodicalExam',$patient);
        $this->load->view('Footer');
}
```

**My Model**

```
public function getPeriodicalChart($id){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('periodical_examination a');
        $this->db->join('patient p','p.id = a.pid');
        $this->db->where('a.pid',$id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
```

Comment: U have a lot of solution now u can test them and mark as accepted otherwise people think its open question.

Answer (score 2):

**In model**

```
return $query->result_array();
```

**In Controller**

```
$result= $this->patient_model->getPeriodicalChart($pid);
$patient = $result[0]['pd']; # zero indexed array pointer
```

Comment: Bro u can also share the other solution of object

Answer (score 2):

result() is recursive in that it returns an std class object where as result_array() just returns a pure array, so result_array() would be choice regarding performance. There is very little difference in speed though.anyone with basic knowledge in php will find easy to read the code

Instead of this lines

```
$query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

(Just use this its really easy to understand)

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Really easy to understand how? What is the diff bw result and result_array?

Comment: result() is recursive in that it returns an std class object where as result_array() just returns a pure array, so result_array() would be choice regarding performance. There is very little difference in speed though.anyone with basic knowledge in php will find easy to read the code

Comment: Good add this in your answer will help to others

Answer (score 1):

It should be an object. Try this

```
<?php echo $pd->id; ?>
```

if there could be more that one result set, then try this

```
<?php echo $pd[0]->id; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->result();
```

is an Object not an array..to return a Array you should use

```
$query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you used  `return $query->result();` in your Model and sent the all table to the view through Controller.
That's great job. All are fine. Now you just use the below code in your view page to `echo` the `id`.

**view (editPeriodicalExam)**

```
<?php
 foreach($pd as $item){
    echo $item['id'];
 } 
?>
```